# How to AutoCall a Province from json array once a State is Clicked in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a project in Reactjs and there is need for the users to enter their States and Provinces. I intend doing the selection automatic, i.e, when a user select a State from a list of JSon Arrays, the Province will automatically populate all province in the State. And as you click on Province, you'll see all the Provinces linked to the State you just selected.

But I truly don't know how to actualize that, hence my coming here for assistance. Especially as all searched results from google and here too aren't giving me headway.

Example of my .json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "state": "StateOne",
    "province": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "state": "StateTwo",
    "province": ["H", "K", "L", "M", "P"]
  }
]
```

My React File:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

import ContactContext from "../../contact/contactContext";

const ContactForm = () => {
  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main-content">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <h4> ADD CONTACT </h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} onload="resetSelection()">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8">

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <label className="form-group has-float-label">
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    id="stateOfOrigin"
                    placeholder="state Of Origin"
                    name=" "
                    value=""
                    onChange={onChange}
                  >
                    <option> </option>
                  </select>
                  <span>state Of Origin</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <label className="form-group has-float-label">
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    id="province"
                    placeholder="province"
                    name=" "
                    value=""
                    onChange={onChange}
                  >
                    <option> </option>
                  </select>
                  <span>province</span>
                </label>
              </div>


          <div className="col-6">
            <button
              type="submit"
              value={current ? "Update Contact" : "Add Contact"}
              className="btn nextBtn btn-cont"
              onClick={onSubmit}
            >
              {current ? "Update Contact" : "Add Contact"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out your `provinces` array based on the state ID. This is using a function component and a state hook, but the same idea would stand with  `this.state.stateId` or similar.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const states = [
  {
    id: "1",
    state: "StateOne",
    province: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    state: "StateTwo",
    province: ["H", "K", "L", "M", "P"],
  },
];

const StateAndProvinceSelector = ({ initialState, onChangeStateAndProvince }) => {
  const [stateId, setStateId] = React.useState(initialState);
  const state = states.find((s) => s.id === stateId);
  const provinces = state ? state.province : null;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Select state:
        <select onChange={(e) => setStateId(e.target.value || null)}>
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          {states.map((s) => (
            <option key={s.id} value={s.id}>
              {s.state}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        Select province:
        <select
          disabled={!provinces}
          onChange={(e) =>
            e.target.value &&
            onChangeStateAndProvince({ stateId, provinceId: e.target.value })
          }
        >
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          {(provinces || []).map((p) => (
            <option key={p} value={p}>
              {p}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <StateAndProvinceSelector
    onChangeStateAndProvince={(result) => alert(JSON.stringify(result))}
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX Nevertheless I have two further questions if you don't mind.
1). Is there anyway I can make the State and Province into a reusable component rather than using it in same place with the "ContactForm" cuz the State and Provinces I want to use are really much, so using it here will really make this "ContactForm" kind of messy;
2). Please where do I add those scripts?

Comment: Naturally. I edited the answer to refactor things just so.